# JavaFX MenuItem without autohide

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I want a MenuItem (more specific a CheckMenuItem) which does not auto hide on click. I know that CustomMenuItem has this functionality, but it should be a CheckMenuItem.

Comment: What's "too broad" with this question??? Besides, I already answered it before it was put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CustomMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html), [setHideOnClick](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#hideOnClickProperty) and a CheckBox in the constructor.

---

*Edit:*

I just noticed that it's messed up in JavaFX 8u40. The menu item text color is the same as the background color, so you don't see any text.

A quick workaround to this is to set the text style, e. g.

```
cb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color");
```

Here's a full example:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            VBox root = new VBox();

             MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

            final Menu menu = new Menu( "Items");

            for( int i=0; i < 10; i++) {

                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox( "Item " + i);

                // workaround: the color of the labels is wrong (white text on white background), we have to set it explicitly
                cb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color");

                CustomMenuItem cmi = new CustomMenuItem( cb);
                cmi.setHideOnClick(false);

                menu.getItems().add( cmi);

            }

            menu.getItems().add( new MenuItem( "This one doesn't stay open"));

            menuBar.getMenus().add( menu);


            root.getChildren().add( menuBar);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeah, this works great, except that The CheckBox does not expand to the full width of the Menu (I have some other items in there with different lengths). Is there a way to fill the width of the menu?