# Prevent hiding of contextmenu after selecting CheckMenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have an contextmenu on a textfield (opens on focus) with 2 CheckMenuItems. Selecting one menuitem leads to hide the contextmenu. How can I prevent contextmenu hiding after selecting an item (to allow more selections)

Exampleapp:

```
public class ContextMenuTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {  
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    CheckMenuItem item1 = new CheckMenuItem("test1");
    CheckMenuItem item2 = new CheckMenuItem("test2");

    contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2);

    TextField textfield = new TextField();
    TextField textfield1 = new TextField();
    textfield.focusedProperty().addListener((object, oldVal, newVal) -> {
      if(newVal)
        contextMenu.show(textfield, Side.TOP, 0, 0);
    });

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(textfield, textfield1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Edit:
I tried setAutoHide(false) but this does not help

Comment: See if [this answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622812/javafx-menuitem-without-autohide).

Comment: @Roland Thank you. It is exactly this what i need. Apparently it is not possible to make it with checkmenuitem.