# JavaFX CheckboxMenuItems / CustomMenuItems Trouble

Tags: java, javafx, menu

I got `CheckBoxMenu` Items in a Menu to select filters I got. I found out that I can't use setHideOnClick on `CheckBoxMenu` so I used `CustomMenuItem` with a `CheckBox` inside, but now I can only click the box and its text to ckeck the box instead of the whole highlightened field. Is there any way to expand it to the width of the `CustomMenuItem`?

I got the same Problem like this:
[JavaFX MenuItem without autohide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622812/javafx-menuitem-without-autohide)
But the solution doesn't work 100% and in a comment there is the same question/problem I have now.

Greets

Comment: provide a code example that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve and how it doesn't meet your requirement, please

Comment: @kleopatra edited it